# ReSharper and Caliburn.Micro's conventions

Tags: wpf, resharper, caliburn.micro

Does anyone know of a plugin for ReSharper 9 that would allow ReSharper to "understand" Caliburn.Micro's conventions?

ReSharper is, for example, complaining that property or method is not used in the ViewModel, because it's been bound automatically using the `Name=` convention. Same thing for buttons and actions.

I could set the `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance MyViewModel}` on the Window/UserControl but it also means rewriting all the bindings explicitely which is annoying and removes one of the nice feature of Caliburn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one, but it's a nice idea for one. You can see the plugin devguide documentation here: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/devguide

Comment: indeed, it's a good idea for a project, but I'm kind of lost on where to start. Would you have an example of a project that would help me get started on that?
Basically, it would require changing the datacontext of the XAML elements depending on the Caliburn conventions, or something similar I guess.
Also, isn't the documentation outdated? In the "Required Tools" section for example, the link to the SDK links to a page where I can't find the SDK to download.

Comment: Well, there are a few parts of the devguide that are out of date - the required tools page is certainly one. The SDK now is just a bunch of nuget packages. The majority of the info in the devguide is still valid. It's always hard to point to good examples, because there is just so much you can do with the SDK that pretty much all plugins are wildly different. There's nothing that messes with XAML bindings, for example. But there are samples that can mark items in use, and provide references between nodes in the tree.

Comment: For example, this will mark elements as in use (based on them being used by xunit unit tests) - https://github.com/xunit/resharper-xunit/blob/ebfa811835e32935387e28f9040d52fd6562a465/resharper/src/provider/SuppressUnusedXunitTestElements.cs

Comment: And this section of the devguide shows how to make references between nodes in the syntax trees: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/devguide/PSI/References.html